# How to add current culture to the HttpContext while rewriting the URL in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to serve pages with culture info in the URL.

For example, `About.cshtml` should serve these URLs:

1. `/about`
2. `/en/about`
3. `/ru/about`

I can achieve that using `app.UseRewrite()`. Here's my code:

```
var options = new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRewrite(@$"/(en|ru|ar)/?(.*$)", "/$2", skipRemainingRules: true);
app.UseRewriter(options);
```

However, I also need to extract the currently selected culture and put it inside `HttpContext.Items`.

How can I do that while rewriting the URL?

Comment: Hi @Ali EXE, you can add a middleware to get the route and put it inside the HttpContext.Items